# Using powershell move folder if match extension

Tags: powershell

there is multiple folders with two extensions `.zip` and `.txt` files. However, if any folder has only a `.zip` or only a `.txt` file, then the move command should not work.

here is something I found, but how can I do it for two extensions?

```
Move-Item -LiteralPath (Get-ChildItem -File -Path N:\Download\*\*.txt).DirectoryName `
          -Destination N:\Zip -Force -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably more efficient ways to do this, but I've used the Where-Object to filter.

```
# Customizable variables
$Source = "N:\Download"
$Destination = "N:\Zip"
$Extension1 = "*.txt"
$Extension2 = "*.zip"

# script
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder |  Where-Object { $_.Name -like $Extension1}) -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder |  Where-Object { $_.Name -like $Extension2})) {
        Move-Item -Path "$Folder\$Extension1" -Destination $Destination -Force -Verbose
        Move-Item -Path "$Folder\$Extension2" -Destination $Destination -Force -Verbose
    }
}
```

Using the variables you can easily customize the script with other source and destination folders or extensions
You could omit the -Verbose output once you've seen it in action.